# Create a ticket with multiple choices Python

Tags: python, list, while-loop, menu

I have a task where I'm supposed to create a ticket where the user first choose which kind of ticket they want and then if they want to add a bag (option 1) or a meal (option 2). The user can also choose to remove a bag (option 3) or a meal (option 4), if they regret their first choice. All the choices are then gonna be printed on a receipt.

My problem is how to store the option that the user choses. I created a while loop that runs until the user want to finalize its ticket. This is my while-loop:

```
while yourchoice != 5:

    if yourchoice == 1:
        addonebag = str('1 bag(s) registered')
        choiceslist.append(addonebag)

    elif yourchoice == 2:
        addonemeal = str('1 meal(s) registered')
        choiceslist.append(addonemeal)

    elif yourchoice == 3:
        removebag = str('0 bag(s) registered')
        choiceslist.pop(addonebag)
        choiceslist.append(removebag)

    elif yourchoice == 4:
        removemeal = str('0 meal(s) registered')
        choiceslist.pop(1,addmeal)
        choiceslist.insert(1,removemeal)

    else: 
        print('\n' 
          'Invalid option. Please try again.')
```

I want the output to look like this depending on the option the user chose (it can also say 1 bag or 1 meal or both):

Currently you have:
0 bag(s) registered
0 meal(s) registered

The problem is that when I create this list the output is if I chose option 1 in the first loop: ['1 bag(s) registered']

If I then chose option 3 in the next loop, the output is: ['1 bag(s) registered' '0 bag(s) registered'] instead of just ['0 bag(s) registered'].

I've tried to use pop and insert on specific indexes but it doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea of how I can solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you need that the type of the ``yourchoice`` variable would be an int ? or it doesn't matter for you if it's a str ?

Comment: You are misunderstanding how `pop()` works. `pop()` only takes an index, not a string. Thus for `yourchoice == 3`, use `pop(0)` and for `yourchoice == 4`, use `pop(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, if this works for you.

As you only needs to get the current choice. I don't think you need to
append into the list. You can store the choices for meal and bag separately and in the end you can create a new list by using both choices.

```
# In the beginning choices should be 0
bag_choice = '0 bag(s) registered'
meal_choice = '0 meal(s) registered'

while yourchoice != 5:

  if yourchoice == 1:
      bag_choice = '1 bag(s) registered'

  elif yourchoice == 2:
      bag_choice = '1 meal(s) registered'

  elif yourchoice == 3:
      bag_choice = '0 bag(s) registered'

  elif yourchoice == 4:
      meal_choice = '0 meal(s) registered'

  else: 
      print('\n' 
            'Invalid option. Please try again.')

#creating a list from bag_choice and meal_choice     
choice_list =  [bag_choice, meal_choice]
print(choice_list)
```

Comment: It is best to explain the changes you made and how does it fix the problem.

Comment: @Chandra you don't need to apply the string method for a string !!!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help! I actually tried another method where I put bag to 1 or 0 depending on the choice and it works!

Now my code looks like this:

```
def tickettype():
    print('Ticket types: \n' 
          '1. Budget: 500 kr \n' 
          '2. Economy: 750 kr \n' 
          '3. VIP: 2000 kr \n')

def options():
    print('\nHere are your options: \n'
          '1. Add bag (max 1) \n'
          '2. Add meal (max 1) \n'
          '3. Remove bag \n'
          '4. Remove meal \n'
          '5. Finalize ticket \n')

tickettype()

tickettype1 = int(input('Choose your ticket type: '))

if tickettype1 == 1:
    ticket = 500

elif tickettype1 == 2:
    ticket = 750

elif tickettype1 == 3:
    ticket = 2000

options()

print('\n' 
    'Currently you have: \n'
      '0 bag(s) registered \n'
      '0 meal(s) registered \n')

yourchoice = int(input('Your choice: '))
bag = 0
meal = 0
addbag = 0
addmeal = 0

while yourchoice != 5:

    if yourchoice == 1:
        bag = 1
        bagprice = 200
        addbag = str('Bag    : 200')

    elif yourchoice == 2:
        meal = 1
        mealprice = 150
        addmeal = str('Meal   : 150')

    elif yourchoice == 3:
        bag = 0

    elif yourchoice == 4:
        meal = 0

    else: 
        print('\n' 
          'Invalid option. Please try again.')

    print('\n' 
        f'Currently you have: \n{bag} bag(s) registered \n{meal} meal(s) registered')

    options()

    yourchoice = int(input('Your choice: '))

# When the user press 5:

#EDITED AFTER THIS LINE


#print(f'\nReceipt:\nTicket : {ticket}\n{addbag}\n{addmeal} \nTotal: {ticket+bagprice+mealprice}'

#create a new variable to store Total price, adding mealprice or bagprice only if they are selected else 0 will be added
Total = (mealprice if meal == 1 else 0) + (bagprice if bag == 1 else 0) + ticket

print(f'\nReceipt:\nTicket:{ticket}')
#print bag only if it is selected, bag value will became 1 only if it is selected
if bag == 1:
  print(addbag)
# print meal only if it is selected, meal value will became 1 only if it is selected
if meal == 1:
  print(addmeal)
# print the Total price
print(f'Total:{Total}')
```

However, it does not print like I want to. For example if I choose ticket no 1 and to add one bag, the output is:

```
Receipt:
Ticket : 500
Bag    : 200
0 
Total: 850
```

But I only want the total to be 700 and I don't want the "0" on the line after "Bag". It stills adds the meal price to the total price and the "0" comes from the line before the while-loop. I put the meal price and the print string for meal in option 3 so I don't know why it still adds the meal price?

So what I want it to look like in the receipt is:

```
Receipt:
Ticket : 500
Bag    : 200
Total: 700
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this? :)

Comment: I have edited your answer according to your requirement. Hope it will help.